# Justify-content: space-between doesn't appear to be working in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, web

I have tried changing a bunch of things in the CSS with classes and id's, but nothing seems to make it so that both images will be on the far side of the screen (logo on the far left and profile on the far right).

Tried lots of different things like `text-align` and different `justify-contents` but nothing appears to work.

Here is the code:

```css
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 10%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.top-nav div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1"><img src="/textures/logo.svg"></div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1"><img src="/textures/profile.svg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74675394/4512005)** suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

justify-content right now does nothing, because it's set on a div that doesn't have display:flex on it.
If you want want the divs with images separeted, then put the justify-content:space-between on the div that has them i.e. the top-nav div.

Comment: That didn't change how it looked either (i tried with justify-content in the container and the div)

Comment: Maybe post a codepen then. I pasted your code into codepen and it seemed to do the trick. But if it's not working for you, maybe something else is the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/d1298/pen/QWxJZqj

Comment: nvm it does work in codepen must be something else in the file. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that you set the flex-items the `top-nav div` elements – the parents of the `<img>` elements – to expand to fill the availlable space; this means the `<div>` elements fill that space, and the `<img>` elements are aligned via the default `text-align` for the language defined by your browser.

Instead you could either remove the `<div`> elements, as they do little to help and bloat the HTML for no reason, and specify `justify-content: space-between` on the `.top-nav` element:

```css
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
</div>
```

Or, you could either retain the `<div>` elements and simply omit the `flex-grow` statement:

```css
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <div><img src="https://placekitten.com/300"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"></div>
</div>
```

Or simply use `text-align` on those `<div>` elements:

```css
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-nav div:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

.top-nav div:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <div><img src="https://placekitten.com/300"></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"></div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align%5D).

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a result similar to this?

```css
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 10%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.top-nav .brand {
  margin-right: auto; /* Push element to the left*/
}

.top-nav .profile {
  margin-left: auto; /* Push element to the right */
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav">
  <div class="brand">
    <img src="/textures/logo.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <img src="/textures/profile.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```